# How can I access data stored as JSON using casts in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, mutators

I entered information into my database like this:

```
public function addFlight(){
    Flight::create([
        'name' => 'Sidney',
        'address' => [
            'street' => 'Williams road',
            'suburb' => 'Parow'
        ]
    ]);
    return "Saved";
}
```

So, in my database, address is stored as json and I have this done inside my model:

```
protected $casts = [
    'address' => 'array'
];
```

What I want now, is to get the address information everytime I am looping through the flights.At the moment I have this:

```
public function getFlight(){
    $flights = Flight::all();
    foreach ($flights as $flight) {
        foreach($flight->address as $address){
            echo $address->street;
        }
    }
}
```

How do I access the address information(street and suburb) ?

At the moment, if I try to access the getFlights method via url, I get the following error:

```
Trying to get property 'street' of non-object
```

Comment: Since you've added `address` in the `$casts` array you should just be able to do `$flight->address` and it will be an array. Is this not the case?

Comment: No its not. I have multiple flights,and for each flight I want to access the address information. each as string.

Comment: Please can you add you're entire `Flight` model and also show your controller code for getting/looping through the flights?